# Concatenate function change

Tags: excel, vba

Result for a single entry has to be
[CAR] and not 0.

CAR is example for single entry. With single entry i always get 0.
With multiple I get [CAR;BIKE]
What do I have to change do get [CAR]
Code:

```
Function ConcRange(ByRef myRange As Range, Optional ByVal Seperator As String = ";", Optional ByVal Begin As String = "[")
Conc = vbNullString
Dim rngCell As Range
For Each rngCell In myRange
If Conc = vbNullString Then
If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
Conc = CStr(rngCell.Value)
End If
Else
If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
Conc = Conc & Seperator & CStr(rngCell.Value)
ConcRange = "[" & Conc & "]"
End If
End If
Next rngCell
End Function
```

Comment: Test if `myRange.Rows.Count * myRange.Columns.Count` = 1 and return [CAR] in that case.

Answer (score 1):

An array approach will be much faster than a range loop

Also, when concatenating strings, minimise the call on long strings, ie

`=ShortStr & (LongStr and ShortStr2)`
is better than the approach below which joins the long string twice

`=ShortStr & LongStr and ShortStr2`

```
Function ConcRange(ByRef myRange As Range, Optional ByVal Separator As String = ";") As String
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim X

If myRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    X = myRange.Value2
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
      For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
        If Len(X(lngRow, lngCol)) > 0 Then
            If Len(ConcRange) > 0 Then
                ConcRange = ConcRange & (Separator & X(lngRow, lngCol))
            Else
                ConcRange = X(lngRow, lngCol)
            End If
      Next lngCol
    Next lngRow
Else
    If Len(myRange.Value2) > 0 Then ConcRange = myRange.Value2
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want:

```
Function ConcRange(ByRef myRange As Range, Optional ByVal Seperator As String = ";", Optional ByVal Begin As String = "[") As String
    If (myRange.Rows.Count * myRange.Columns.Count = 1) Then
        ConcRange = "[" & myRange.Cells(1,1).Value & "]"
    End If
    Conc = vbNullString
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In myRange
    If Conc = vbNullString Then
        If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        Conc = CStr(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    Else
        If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        Conc = Conc & Seperator & CStr(rngCell.Value)
        ConcRange = "[" & Conc & "]"
        End If
    End If
    Next rngCell
End Function
```

*disclaimer: I don't have access to Excel at the moment to test.

Answer (score 0):

With your current code the function gets only a return value if the `ELSE` was reached. That is only if there are more than one cell in the `myRange`.

But it should get a return value everytime:

```
Function ConcRange(ByRef myRange As Range, Optional ByVal Seperator As String = ";") As String
 Dim Conc As String
 Conc = vbNullString
 Dim rngCell As Range
 For Each rngCell In myRange
  If Conc = vbNullString Then
   If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
    Conc = CStr(rngCell.Value)
   End If
  Else
   If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
    Conc = Conc & Seperator & CStr(rngCell.Value)
   End If
  End If
 Next rngCell
 ConcRange = "[" & Conc & "]"
End Function
```

Hint: Indenting the code helps better understand the dependencies.